# Is there another palindrome-Carmichael-number?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, pseudoprimes, palindrome

$$101101$$ is a cute number indeed. It is the smallest palindrome-Carmichael-number. Furthermore, its square and its cube are also palindrome! And it is
a "binary" number containing only the digits $0$ and $1$.

There is no other palindrome-Carmichael-number upto $10^9$.

> Is there another palindrome-Carmichael-number ?

Comment: palindrome in ... base 10?

Comment: Yes, I am only interested in base-10-palindromes.

Comment: You can check until $1713045574801$ [here](https://oeis.org/A002997/b002997.txt).

Comment: the 3955-th is $127008810721$. close:)

Comment: A simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q="palindromic+Carmichael+number") reveals plenty of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$127665878878566721$

I used the annotated PSP-2 list from Feitsma and Galway, used a Perl script to find palindromes and verify Carmichael.  That and $101101$ are the only ones in the file.

Comment: Well Done, Dana!